# Is there a way investigate an "invalid Assertion" received when attempting OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow in Salesforce

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, salesforce, jwt

I have written a java client as per Salesforce's [OAuth JWT Bearer Token Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&language=en_US) but the response is "Invalid Assertion". The Certificate I have uploaded to the Salesforce organisation is self-signed and the claim I am sending consists of the client_id (the OAuth connected app's consumer key), the email address/user name of the user (which is also the email declared in the certificate and the user is already successfully using the Salesforce REST API via user/password OAuth flow), an expiry time and the audience is set to https://login.salesforce.com (aud). I can see the 'Digital Signature' has been loaded correctly in Salesforce and that my code correctly signs it. My Oauth scope in Salesforce has been set to:

> Access and manage your data (api)
>   
> Provide access to your data via the Web (web)
>   
> Perform requests on your behalf at any time (refresh_token, offline_access)

I get the same response when I POST the JWT directly to /services/oauth2/token form, as below:

> grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=k5ARCVFd1VgfOuM...

I include the header:

> "Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

The JWT is generated using:

```
import com.payliquid.model.config.OAuthCredentials;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

public class JWTGenerator {

  public static final String HEADER = "{\"alg\":\"RS256\"}";
  public static final String CLAIM_TEMPLATE = "'{'\"iss\": \"%s\", \"prn\": \"%s\", \"aud\": \"%s\", \"exp\": \"%s\"'}'";
  public static final String ALGORITHM = "SHA256withRSA";

  private String audience;
  private KeyStore keystore;

  public JWTGenerator(String authServerURL, KeyStore keystore) {
    this.audience = authServerURL;
    this.keystore = keystore;
  }

  public String generateToken(OAuthCredentials oAuthCredentials, String clientId) {

    final String certPassword = oAuthCredentials.getPassword();
    final String principal = oAuthCredentials.getUserName();
    final String certAlias = oAuthCredentials.getSecurityToken().get();

    try {
        StringBuilder jwTokenBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        appendEncodedHeader(jwTokenBuilder);

        appendSeparator(jwTokenBuilder);

        final String joinedClaim = String.format(CLAIM_TEMPLATE, getClaimElements(clientId, principal));

        appendEncodedClaim(jwTokenBuilder, joinedClaim);

        PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKey(certPassword, certAlias);

        String signedPayload = signPayload(jwTokenBuilder, privateKey);

        appendSeparator(jwTokenBuilder);

        jwTokenBuilder.append(signedPayload);

        return jwTokenBuilder.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new OAuthRuntimeSystemException("Could not generate JWT Token", e);
    }
  }

  private PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String certPassword, String certAlias) throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    PrivateKey privateKey = loadPrivateKey(certAlias, certPassword);

    if (privateKey == null) {
        throw new OAuthRuntimeSystemException("Could not generate JWT Token as no private key available with " + certAlias);
    }
    return privateKey;
  }

  private String[] getClaimElements(String iss, String prn) {
    return new String[]{
            iss,
            prn,
            audience,
            getExpirationTime()};
 }

  private String getExpirationTime() {
    return new DateTime().plusMinutes(1).toDate().getTime() + "";
 }

  private void appendSeparator(StringBuilder token) {
    token.append(".");
 }

  private PrivateKey loadPrivateKey(String certAlias, String privateKeyPassword) throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    return (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(certAlias, privateKeyPassword.toCharArray());
}

 private String signPayload(StringBuilder token, PrivateKey privateKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    signature.initSign(privateKey);
    signature.update(getBytesInCharSet(token.toString()));
    return encode(signature.sign());
}

  private void appendEncodedClaim(StringBuilder token, String claim) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    token.append(encode(claim));
}

  private void appendEncodedHeader(StringBuilder token) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    token.append(encode(HEADER));
}

  private String encode(String payload) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final byte[] bytes = getBytesInCharSet(payload);
    return encode(bytes);
}

  private byte[] getBytesInCharSet(String s) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return s.getBytes("UTF-8");
  }

  private String encode(byte[] bytes) {
    return Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get more information as to why the assertion failed or is there more I need to do to the JWT or the Salesforce Connected App or User to get this to work?

Comment: You can verify your JWT here: http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/tool_verifyanalyze.html; seems weird that your base64url encoded assertion would start with "k5ARCVFd1VgfOuM...", it would rather start with "eyJ..."

Comment: Thanks for the verification page. My unsigned JWT assertion does begin with eyJ but when I sign it with my private key it becomes X12-CSN_ ... (I've changed my cert!) .If I put my pre-signed assertion onto the page along with my X509 cert, it correctly parses my header and payload but not a sig value. I'm joining my header and payload and signing that, rather than appending the 'SigValue'. That's obviously my mistake but what is the SigValue?

Comment: I think I got it: SigValue is the signed header +"." + "payload"?

Comment: the signature value is calculated over the message value `base64urlencode(header)` + "." + `base64urlencode(payload)` and then that signature is base64urlencoded and concatenated to the message value , so: `JWT = base64urlencode(header) + "." . base64urlencode(payload) + "." + base64urlencode(signature)`

Comment: Thanks for your help, my code is now working correctly.

Comment: I have similar issue, I validated with above tool and followed instructions to tee from here https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&language=en_US#create_token still see an "invalid assertion" issue. Is there any difference in setting OAuth with JWT on salesforce?